# Can <i></i> tag be a self closing tag in JSX?

Tags: typescript, reactjs, tsx

I followed [Airbnb React/JSX style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react), it said that "**Always self-close tags that have no children**".

Is it also be valid for `<i></i>` tag that generally has no children? Can it be written as `<i className="fa fa-info" />` in JSX?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What's the point of a styling tag with no content to style? Just curious, it is not relevant to your question.

Comment: @nitzan-tomer: Yes, I have. I just curious it was a best practice or not for <i> tag.

Comment: @rici: It was a font-awesome icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, I just put together a codesandbox and it appears to be working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/XoMNlLzpo

[image]